# Tracking history of vehicles and drivers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm experimenting with relations in Laravel and I cannot figure this one out.

I have two tables `users` and `vehicles`. The users can drive a vehicle and the drivers are replaced often. To track these changes I created a `history` table. This table contains `user_id`, `vehicle_id`, `start` and `end`.
I want to get the vehicle that the current user is driving, through the History table.

```
class User extends model {
    public function vehicle() 
    {
        // return the current active vehicle for the user
        // through the History model.
        return $this->hasOne(History::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function history() 
    {
        // return all the vehicles that the user has used
        // this currently returns the history rows, not the cars
        return $this->hasMany(History::class, 'user_id');
    }
}

class Vehicle extends model {
    public function user() 
    {
        // return the current active user
    }

    public function users() 
    {
        // return all the users that used this vehicle
    }
}
```

If I perform the following method in a controller.

```
public function showUser()
{
    return User::findOrFail(1)->with('vehicle', 'history')->get()
}
```

I want the response formatted like the following:

```
[
  0: {
    first_name: 'John',
    ...
    vehicle: {
      model: 'BMW ...'
    }
    history: {
      0: {
        model: 'BMW ...'
      }
      1: {
        model: 'Audi ...'
      }
      ...
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: And what is your __question__?

Comment: "*// But returns the history row, not the vehicle"* Well, look at your relationship; you're using `hasOne(History::class, ...`), should that maybe be `Vehicle::class`? Also, if your method name is `vehicles`, it won't display as `history: { ... }`; consider changing your `public function vehicles()` to `public function history()`

Comment: @TimLewis I've added the `hasOne(Histo...` as example, replacing with `Vehicle::class` does not work, there is no reference to the vehicle on the users table. I want to access the vehicle through the `History` model if possible.

Comment: Might be helpful to edit your question and post the migration for `users`, `vehicles` and `history`, or at the very least the id's and how everything connects. I can only make guesses currently.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) to your history model to return the latest record.

```
public function scopeLatest($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1);
}
```

Then you can get that through your relationship

```
$user->history()->latest()->first()->vehicle;
```

This, of course, requires that you have the vehicle relationship defined in your history class.